# Entity Framework 6 selecting items based on a field in a child item

Tags: c#, entity-framework

EF6 MVC5

I have an `Orders` table. Each order has a `Customer`.

I am trying to seach for `Orders` that have a customer with a `surname` that contains a string.

So one `Order` has one `Customer` but a `Customer` can have many `Orders`.

I can't quite get what I need. I'm assuming it's better (more efficient?) to get the customer first then get the orders, rather than get all orders and then filter on Customer - so here are my attempts:

```
List<Order> orders = new List<Order>();
orders = db.Contacts.Where(c => c.NameLast.Contains(surnameContains)).Select(c => c.Orders).ToList();
```

The above gives the error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List>'
>   to 'System.Collections.Generic.List'

So I'm thinking the above is returning a List of List of `Orders` - which makes sense - a List of Customers and each `Customer` contains a List of `Orders`. I think maybe I can `addRange`:

```
orders.AddRange(db.Contacts.Where(c => c.NameLast.Contains(surnameContains)).Select(c => c.Orders));
```

This doesn't work either - error=

> Argument 1: cannot convert from
>   'System.Linq.IQueryable>'
>   to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'

I'd be really grateful for any pointers to help with this. The result I would like is a List of `Order`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Orders table, do you have a Customer/Contact field? If yes, you can test the following :

```
List<Order> orders = new List<Order>();
orders = db.Orders.Where(o => o.Customer.NameLast.Contains(surnameContains)).ToList();
```

If in your Orders table, you just have a Customer/Contact ID, you can test the following :

```
List<int> ListeID = db.Contacts.Where(c => c.NameLast.Contains(surnameContains)).Select(c => c.ID).ToList();
List<Order> orders = new List<Order>();
orders = db.Orders.Where(o => ListeID.Contains(o.CustomerID)).ToList();
```

or something along those lines.

Comment: my God!!! your first solution worked... and so simple!!! feeling like a right mug now lol! I'm obviously over thinking it! Thanks